# Determine if a DataGridView's horizontal scroll bar exists?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, .net-3.5, scrollbar

Visual Basic 2010, .NET 3.5
Is there a way to pragmatically determine if a DataGridView's horizontal scroll bar is active or visible?  I need to move a few items about when the DGV's horizontal scroll bar comes on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to give you an idea (I have no time right now , or visual studio in front of me):

```
   For Each c In DataGridView1.Controls
        If c.GetType() Is GetType(VScrollBar) Then
            Dim vbar as VScrollBar= DirectCast(c, VScrollBar)
            If vbar.Visible = True Then
               'Do whatever you like
            End If
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: I took your example, made a few adjustments and arrived at way to determine if the scroll bar is visible. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry if the code wasn't totally correct, but I build it in my mind.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

`dgvYourDataGridView.Controls.OfType(Of HScrollBar).SingleOrDefault.Visible`

Comment: Selected answer is correct, But this to me is a cleaner method. `Dim DGVVerticalScroll = MyDataGridViewControl.Controls.OfType(Of VScrollBar).SingleOrDefault`

Comment: UpVote from me, for this elegant solution

Answer (score 2):

Here is the VB.Net version of raising an event when the scrollbar visibility changes, from [How to detect the vertical scrollbar in a DataGridView control](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2685797/719186)

```
Public Class MyGrid
  Inherits DataGridView

  Public Event ScrollbarVisibleChanged As EventHandler

  Public Sub New()
    AddHandler Me.HorizontalScrollBar.VisibleChanged, _
               AddressOf HorizontalScrollBar_VisibleChanged
  End Sub

  Public ReadOnly Property HorizontalScrollbarVisible() As Boolean
    Get
      Return HorizontalScrollBar.Visible
    End Get
  End Property

  Private Sub HorizontalScrollBar_VisibleChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    RaiseEvent ScrollbarVisibleChanged(Me, EventArgs.Empty)
  End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 2):

I took Nianios example, made a few adjustments and arrived at way to determine if the scroll bar is visible.  Thanks!

```
Private Function HScrollBarVisible() As Boolean
    Dim ctrl As New Control
    For Each ctrl In DataGridView1.Controls
        If ctrl.GetType() Is GetType(HScrollBar) Then
            If ctrl.Visible = True Then
                Return True
            Else
                Return False
            End If
        End If
    Next
    Return Nothing
End Function
```