# check if a scroll bar is visible in a datagridview

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I would like to display something if the data grid View is long and showing a scroll bar but don't know how to check if the scroll bar is visible. I can't simply add the rows since some may be not visible. I can't use an event since my code is already in an event.

Comment: Need more details. What did you try? what exactly do you want to do ?

Comment: I am adding an indicator next to the scroll bar indicating where important information is, similar to visual studio.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly do you mean. Did you try this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2685651/how-to-detect-the-vertical-scrollbar-in-a-datagridview-control or just checking for `Visible` property of scrollbar?

Comment: thanks that link help a lot. I used dataGridView1.Controls.OfType<VScrollBar>().First().visible;

Answer (score 17, accepted):

you can try this out:

```
foreach (var scroll in dataGridView1.Controls.OfType<VScrollBar>())
{
   //your checking here
   //specifically... if(scroll.Visible)
}
```

Comment: ended up using that method to get a datagridview to the correct width, though it means incrementing the width of the datagridview by one until horizontal scrollbars aren't visible   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37635932/calculate-padding-of-datagridview-when-padding-is-greater-than-two     If you know of a more efficient way do let me know. Ta

Answer (score 11):

I prefer this one :

```
//modif is a modifier for the adjustment of the Client size of the DGV window
//getDGVWidth() is a custom method to get needed width of the DataGridView

int modif = 0;
if (DataGridView.Controls.OfType<VScrollBar>().First().Visible)
{
    modif = SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth;
}
this.ClientSize = new Size(getDGVWidth() + modif, [wantedSizeOfWindow]);
```

so the only Boolean condition you need is:

```
if (DataGridView.Controls.OfType<VScrollBar>().First().Visible)
{
    //want you want to do
}
```

Comment: Nice solution. I suggest to add an additional check because First() could throws an exception: `var vScrollBar = dgvEntity.Controls.OfType<VScrollBar>().FirstOrDefault();
            if (vScrollBar != null && vScrollBar.Visible)
                vScrollbarWidth = SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth;`

Answer (score 4):

The `DataGridView`'s `Scrollbars` **Property** can be questioned using the `ScrollBars` **Enumeration** by masking it with the one you are interested in like this:

```
if ((dataGridView1.ScrollBars & ScrollBars.Vertical) != ScrollBars.None) ...
```

Note, that the two 'ScrollBars' are different things here!

Comment: well this program creates a datagridview, which certain'y has no scroll bars though that line shows it as having them http://pastebin.com/raw/vfu6j09T

Comment: Sory, but I don't understand.

Comment: I think I was saying that in the code at the pastebin link it always shows that messagebox even when the datagridview has no scroll bars

Answer (score 3):

The answer from terrybozzio works only if you use the `System.Linq` namespace.
A solution without using `System.Linq` is shown below:

```
foreach (var Control in dataGridView1.Controls)
{
    if (Control.GetType() == typeof(VScrollBar))
    {
        //your checking here
        //specifically... if (((VScrollBar)Control).Visible)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To determine if the vertical scrollbar is present, you need to check how tall your visible rows are and compare against the datagridview height.

```
if(dgv1.Height > dgv1.Rows.GetRowsHeight(DataGridViewElementStates.Visible))
{
    // Scrollbar not visible
}
else
{
    // Scrollbar visible
}
```

Though to be more exact you may need to include a check of column widths as the presence of a horizontal scrollbar could create a vertical scrollbar that otherwise isn't there.